# Reopening a closed stringIO object in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, file-io

So, I create a StringIO object to treat my string as a file:

```
>>> a = 'Me, you and them\n'
>>> import io
>>> f = io.StringIO(a)
>>> f.read(1)
'M'
```

And then I proceed to close the 'file':

```
>>> f.close()
>>> f.closed
True
```

Now, when I try to open the 'file' again, Python does not permit me to do so:

```
>>> p = open(f)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#166>", line 1, in <module>
    p = open(f)
TypeError: invalid file: <_io.StringIO object at 0x0325D4E0>
```

Is there a way to 'reopen' a closed StringIO object? Or should it be declared again using the io.StringIO() method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I have a nice hack, which I am currently using for testing (Since my code can make I/O operations, and giving it StringIO is a nice get-around).

If this problem is kind of one time thing:

```
st = StringIO()
close = st.close
st.close = lambda: None
f(st)  # Some function which can make I/O changes and finally close st
st.getvalue()  # This is available now
close() # If you don't want to store the close function you can also:
StringIO.close(st)
```

If this is recurring thing, you can also define a context-manager:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def uncloseable(fd):
    """
    Context manager which turns the fd's close operation to no-op for the duration of the context.
    """
    close = fd.close
    fd.close = lambda: None
    yield fd
    fd.close = close
```

which can be used in the following way:

```
st = StringIO()
with uncloseable(st):
    f(st) 
# Now st is still open!!!
```

I hope this helps you with your problem, and if not, I hope you will find the solution you are looking for.
Note: This should work exactly the same for other file-like objects.

Comment: This hack could be improved because, as is, it is not very pythonic: if you want to overwrite the close method of a file descriptor, you should really create a class that makes it, it's one of their purpose! For example, you could create a class Uncloseable that would be a proxy of any file-like given except for the close method, which would do nothing, and add a real_close method which would really do the close stuff (because you should always close a stream after you open it).

Comment: I need to prevent closing the output in my tests too! I shouldn't change the code that I am testing, so this is the best hack! Disabling the close method.

Comment: Comment to @HamzaAbbad
BlackBeans is still right about having finally close the file. It's always a good practice to do so.
I don't quite agree it's not pythonic, it's a use of monkey patching, which is very common for python testing.

Comment: hacky but i like it! perfect for my one off testing issue

Answer (score 8):

No, there is no way to re-open an `io.StringIO` object. Instead, just create a new object with `io.StringIO()`.

Calling `close()` on an `io.StringIO` object throws away the "file contents" data, so re-opening couldn't give access to that anyways.

If you need the data, call `getvalue()` before closing.

See also [the `StringIO` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) here:

> The text buffer is discarded when the close() method is called.

and here:

> `getvalue()`
>
> Return a str containing the entire contents of the buffer.

Answer (score 4):

The builtin [open()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#open) creates a file object (i.e. a stream), but in your example, f is already a stream.
That's the reason why you get TypeError: invalid file

After the method [close()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/io.html#io.IOBase.close) has executed, any stream operation will raise ValueError.
And the documentation does not mention about how to reopen a closed stream.

Maybe you need not close() the stream yet if you want to use (reopen) it again later.

Answer (score 0):

When you `f.close()` you remove it from memory. You're basically doing a deref x, call x; you're looking for a memory location that doesn't exist.

Here is what you could do in stead:

```py
import io

a = 'Me, you and them\n'
f = io.StringIO(a)
f.read(1)
f.close()

# Put the text form a without the first char into StringIO.
p = io.StringIO(a[1:]).
# do some work with p.
```

I think your confusion comes form thinking of [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/io.html) as a file on the block device. If you used `open()` and not `StringIO`, then you would be correct in your example and you could reopen the file. `StringIO` is not a file. It's the *idea* of a file object in memory. A file object does have a `StringIO`, but It also exists physically on the block device. A `StringIO` is just a buffer, a staging area in memory of the data with in it. When you call `open()` a buffer is created, but there is still the data on block device.

Perhaps this is more what you want

```py
fo = open('f.txt','w+')
fo.write('Me, you and them\n')

fo.read(1)
fo.close()

# reopen the now closed file `f`
p = open('f.txt','r')
# do stuff with p
p.close()
```

Here we are writing the string to the block device, so that when we close the file, the information written to it will remain after it's closed. Because this is creating a file in the directory the progarm is run in, it may be a good idea to give the file an extension. For example, you could name the file `f.txt` instead of `f`.