# How to use Scapy in Python 3 to write a PCAP to a byte or string?

Tags: python, scapy

I am trying to get a PCAP into a byte variable, but I cannot figure out how to do it. So far I have something like:

```
import io
from scapy.all import *

packet = Ether() / IP(dst="1.2.3.4") / UDP(dport=123)
packet = IP(src='127.0.0.1', dst='127.0.0.2')/TCP()/"GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"

content = b''
wrpcap(io.BytesIO(content), [packet])
```

But `content` is empty. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

You're using `BytesIO` incorrectly. `content` is not the contents of the stream after it's been written to, it's the initial value of the stream.

Additionally `wrpcap` closes the file (or file-like object) after writing to it so you can no longer retrieve the data written to the `BytesIO` object. You can get around this with a hack suggested in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30510282/reopening-a-closed-stringio-object-in-python-3).

```py
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def uncloseable(fd):
    """
    Context manager which turns the fd's close operation to no-op for the duration of the context.
    """
    close = fd.close
    fd.close = lambda: None
    yield fd
    fd.close = close

content = io.BytesIO()
with uncloseable(content):
    wrpcap(content, [packet])

content.seek(0)
print(content.read())
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. I'm new to Python, so I'd love a little more info on how/why it works (e.g. I don't know what the line `@contextlib.contextmanager` does), but the code was just what I needed. Thank you.